# Why scala does not finish function in Catch

Tags: scala, try-catch, playframework-2.1

I validate my function, if an exception is thrown during validation, i wish to stop the method in the catch and return, from some reason, it will continue and only caught in the main try /catch.

Code:

```
def updateProduct(request: UpdateProductRequest): BaseResponse[String] = 
{
  try
  {
      try
      {
          ValidateUpdateProductRequest(request)
      }
      catch
      {
         case ex: Exception => {
           val errorResponse:ErrorResponse[String] = ErrorResponse(ErrorCode.InvalidParameters, ex.getMessage, 500)
           errorResponse // <=- This does not return from function.. In debug i get here
         }
      }
      val deleteProductResult = productRepository.updateProduct(request) //I dont want to get here !!
      DTOResponse(deleteProductResult)
  }
  catch
  {
     case ex: Exception => {
       Logger.error("Failed to update product Id = " +request.product.id, ex);
       var errorResponse:ErrorResponse[String] = ErrorResponse(ErrorCode.GeneralError, ex.getMessage, 500)
       errorResponse
     }
  }
}
```

I Understand in scala the last line of function is the only place function will return, so how do i return from the catch ?
The reason is i want to use different *ErrorCode* in the BaseResponse[string]

Thanks!

Comment: Stupid question, but are you sure to be throwing an exception in your `ValidateUpdateProductRequest` method ? It could be that the main `catch` you're passing in is because of another exception, ocuring for example in `updateProduct`...

Comment: Yes, i debugged it step by step, i am getting to the line of the catch of the second try.. but the function does not return from that, it continues to val deleteProductResult = productRepository.updateProduct(..) and then get null reference since product is null - and thats part of the validation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have an inner expression that you want to propagate to the outermost level to be the result, you can either assign it to a temporary variable in an outer expression, or use `return`.  So, for example:

```
def foo: Int = {
  try { bar }
  catch { case ikte: IKnowTheAnswerException => return 42 }
  lotsOfMath
}

def foo: Int = {
  val iKnowIt = {
    try { bar }
    catch { case ikte: IKnowTheAnswerException => Some(42) }
  }
  iKnowIt.getOrElse( lotsOfMath )
}
```

Even though the second pattern seems uselessly wordy, keep in mind that jumping out of the method with a `return` is not always obvious, especially in longer methods.  So the second can, in some cases, be clearer to read (especially when you know to expect the pattern).

Comment: I understand return in the middle of function is not "best practice" and even against the principles of scala.. so i think i should try to avoid it

Comment: @ilansch - You should write code that solves your problem as cleanly and clearly as possible.  This may mean using `return`!  Just be aware there is an alternate pattern (my second example) that can have advantages.

Comment: maybe you could assist also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381645/how-to-break-rest-controller-that-return-action-in-scala-play-framework  thanks alot.