# How to break REST controller that return Action in Scala/Play framework

Tags: scala, rest, playframework, action

I have a controller that runs some code, I wrap some code in try/catch and wish to break the controller run during catch and return the error.
It does not return, How can I wrap my response in action function as required?

Sample:

```
 def updateProduct(productId : String, lang : String, t : String) = Action {
request =>
  request.body.asJson.map {
    json =>
      var product : Product = null
      try {
        product = json.as[Product]
      }
      catch {
        case ex : Exception => {
          val errorResponse : ErrorResponse[String] = ErrorResponse(ErrorCode.InvalidParameters, ex.getMessage, 500)
          return InternalServerError(Json.toJson(errorResponse)) //Does not stop,
        }
      }

      val response = productService.updateProduct(UpdateProductRequest(lang, t, productId, product))

      if (response.isError) {
        InternalServerError(Json.toJson(response))
      }
      else {
        Ok(Json.toJson(response))
      }
  }.getOrElse {
    Logger.warn("Bad json:" + request.body.asText.getOrElse("No data in body"))
    var errorResponse : ErrorResponse[String] = ErrorResponse(ErrorCode.GeneralError, "Error processing request", 500)
    errorResponse.addMessage("No data in body")
    Ok(Json.toJson(errorResponse))
  }
```

}

I get an error:

```
method `updateProduct` has return `statement`; needs result type
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use `return` you must, as it says, use an explicit return type.  Scala will not infer it for you.

So, for example:

```
def fails(i: Int) = return (i+1)       // Doesn't compile
def works(i: Int): Int = return (i+1)  // Does
```

I am not sure what the common supertype of `Ok` and `InternalServerError` is, but that would be what you're after.  If it's an unhelpful type like `AnyRef` (i.e. `Object`), using `Either` or the equivalent might be a good idea (i.e. `Left(InternalServerError/*...*/)`, `Right(Ok/*...*/)`).

Comment: The common supertype is `SimpleResult`: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.SimpleResult